# How to use john the ripper to create fixed length big letters passwords?

Tags: linux, passwords, mathematica

I want to use john (I hope it's possible) to create all possible combinations of the set A,B,C,D..,Z with fixed 8 length, and distinct letters!

**Meaning:**

ABCFGRTH

QPFLDMRB

etc...

I've tried it with some backtracking algorithms, but they didn't gave me the right results.

Do you guys have any ideas ?

Comment: wolfram alpha may be able to help you find all 1-26 length strings that are permutations of the latin alphabet. http://blog.wolframalpha.com/2011/11/29/working-with-permutations-in-wolframalpha/

Comment: Including upper/lower case variations, that's about 5 times 10^13 permutations. Even if you could try 10^6 passwords per second, that would mean some 2 years of efforts. So it is not practical. Is it theoretically challenging? No way: 8 nested loops will do the trick in any programming language. So the point is learning john the ripper's grammar. There are more economical ways.

Answer (score 0):

For generating dictionaries I use [crunch](http://crunch-wordlist.sourceforge.net/) or [maskprocessor](http://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=maskprocessor) or [statsprocessor](http://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=statsprocessor) from hashcat's utilities and then feed the results into `john --pipe`

Comment: I also used crunch, but with crunch, if I want all letters to be different in each password, it ignores the min length and max. It will create passwords with length 26

Comment: Then use maskprocessor with `?u?u?u?u?u?u?u?u`

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help though my answer is late since the question is the past two years.
Download L517.exe, this will help generate all unique sets from given characters. Words generated are best for hashcat since hashcat uses combination mode of attack. Though the latest version of L517.exe fails when trying to generate 6 characters, dont worry, just configure l517.exe to split the generated list into separate files. then merge them in only one file using Merge.Bat. Merge that bat is a tool written in batch code to merge two or more txt files. it only took 2 minutes to merge 32 text file 78mb each.